# csrf-token POST 405 (Method Not Allowed) Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, csrf

I am loading a modal whenever a user tries to register

**Blade**

```
<form method="POST" id="registerUser" autocomplete="signupForm-noFill" action={{url("/register")}}>
...
    <div class="form-group text-center" style="">
        <button type="submit" role="button" class="btn btn-hp-modal btn-signup">Sign up</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    $("#registerUser").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            method : 'POST',
            success : function(data){
                $("#legalModal").modal("show");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

I have it in other pages and it seems to work fine. Any idea what might be wrong in my approach? I just get `POST http://example.net/signup 405 (Method Not Allowed)` error whenever I Sign Up.

Comment: Show your routes and your controller that handles the request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `url` to `ajax` object:

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    method : 'POST',
    url: '/register',
    success : function(data){
        $("#legalModal").modal("show");
    }
});
```

Comment: Yep, that was that. Thanks!
Will accept in 9 minutes.