# MethodNotAllowedException when send post form with csrf_token Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, forms, validation, post, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to access my "store" (POST) method from my route resource. I call the ProductCRUD.store method from a form that can have different input depending on the previous page. I mean by that, depending if the object i receive have certain boolean value, the input is shown.

```
@if($category->havePrice == 1)
  {!! Form::label('price', 'Price') !!}
  {!! Form::text('price', '', array('id' => 'price', 'name' => "price") !!}
@endif
```

When I click on the button to send the form, I got a message saying 
    MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 251:...

I tried to add a csrf token with the method csrf_field() too.
I tried to empty the cache of laravel with those two methods:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
```

I tried to create a personal route like this:

```
Route::post('/product/store',  array('as' => 'product', 'uses' => 'ProductController@store'));
```

None of those solution works. Always that exception.

My current code:

#### Route:

```
Route::resource('ProductCRUD','ProductController');
```

#### Form

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('ProductCRUD.store')}}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
```

#### Controller method:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $newGameModel= new GameModel();
    $category = $this->CategoryRepo->getByID($request->category);

    $this->validate($request, [
        'name'=> 'required',
        'picture'=> 'required|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,gif,png|max:5000',
        'quantite' => 'required|min:0',
        'price' => 'required_if:'.$category->havePrice.',1',
    ]);
    ...
}
```

If I remove the "$this->validate(...)" method the code continues to execute (no more MethodNotAllowedException error). I tried to comment one by one validation it changes nothing.

Plus, if I reload the page, the input error are shown correctly. If i click again to send the form, surprise! The error again.

Edit:
I send my form using only a button and the form, no ajax:

```
{!! Form::submit('Next step', 'name'=>"accept", 'methode' => "post")) !!}
```

Plus, I can access my controller code. If I remove the validate method, everything work find

Do you guys have any idea why it's doing that? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [csrf-token POST 405 (Method Not Allowed) Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48118148/csrf-token-post-405-method-not-allowed-laravel)

Comment: thank for your reply @bt .l i tried the solution in the link you send and it's not working.

Like i said in my post, the moment i remove the validate method, everything work fine. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I found the problem and how to fix it (not what I wanted to do).
First, I don't have any error in my code. My post, csrf and my routes are all good.

The problem is how larval validates things. For example, If your first page was a post form and your second page is also a post form, when you validate on the second page and it fails, it will try to return to the second page to show the error. But the fact is, it can't find the response of your first page, so you got an error like I got.

I fix it by removing the first form (it was, for me, a little information I can put somewhere else). But I don't know if there is a better way to fix it.